# Android Strange behavior for ImageOperations and downloading from AWS S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Gonna use pseudo names to protect privacy.

My code is this:

```
bitmap = ImageOperations(ImageViewer.this, url, "image.jpg");
```

where url is something like:

https://something.s3.amazonaws.com/photo/koala.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=JDFHHKFHDMASHDFVXJA&Expires=1328514718&Signature=876djncia7458ak%3D

I'm using AWS S3 Query String Request Authentication Alternative to download the file.

I load an activity which downloads the image and shows the bitmap in an ImageView.

```
For the first time, it loads fine and there is a bitmap.
For the second time, it loads and I get null.
For the third time, it loads fine and there is a bitmap.
For the fourth time, it loads and I get null.
```

This alternating behavior is very consistent. Anyone experienced this before and knows what is happening?

I've tried it with a bucket with a no holds barred policy where you can do a direct download without authentication and it works all the time.